# Using the Singleton pattern for Game class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working on a web game using HTML5 websockets and Java as backend. Currently creating a new instance of the game class for every player, which also creates a timer with a timer task to run the game loop and send updates to the frontend every 60fps.

As these timers would be very heavy on server resources with alot of players playing, I was thinking to apply the Singleton pattern in the game class and keep an array of matches. Instead of creating a timer for every single player, I would create 1 single timer that updates the game loop with a for loop for every match in the array.

I wonder if there is a better approach, as i've heard there are alot of cons that come with the singleton pattern especially for unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question right, you want to use 1 timer for all the matches, and use a for-loop for each match to update the game.

That is a horrible idea. Any kind of render blocking anywhere along that line will affect the entire server. If someone on the first match sends a large amount of data to the server, that blocks the thread and slows down the FPS for **every single match**.

Yes, timers are heavy on the server. But using one timer for all the matches causes thread blocking if you have too many active matches at once because the single thread can't handle that high load AND run at 60 FPS.

The probably best way to design any given game server is using Threads.

You can use Thread.sleep to create a delay and maintain a given FPS, and using threads instead of timers lightens the load. IT's still heavy, but using Threads is lighter than Timers.

As for the actual thread, this is a part of it:

```
public void run(){


 long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;//The FPS. Can be reduced or increased.
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;//1 second = 10^9 nanoseconds
    long lastFpsTime = 0;//Used to calculate delta
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();//Get the current time
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;//get the time it took to update
        lastLoopTime = now;//set the last time the loop started to the current time
        double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);//Calculate delta

        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000){
            lastFpsTime = 0;
        }

        //Right here you place your code. Update the servers, push and read data, whatever you need

        try{
            long gt = (lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000;//calculate the time to sleep, and convert to milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(gt);//And finally, sleep to maintain FPS
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

The class extends Thread and has a boolean called `running`. The boolean allows for the Thread to be stopped without having to throw an exception.

You create one thread for each match (that's an important point. Do it for each player and you kill resources. Do one for all the matches, you can't possibly maintain 60 FPS unless you have a super computer (depending on the amount of matches)), and have a main thread for managing the connections and match threads

Answer (score 0):

The simplest rule for singelton design pattern is -

1. Create a private constructor
2. Create a static block-> inside this  place the code which you want to instantiate only one time throughout the project
3. create one static method and then return that object
4. To fulfill step 3 declare one private static instance variable.

Consider example of configure and buildsessionfactory method of hibernate to make this as singelton what i recommend is

```
public class Singelton {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory=null;
    static {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
        }

    private Singelton() {
    }
}
```